# is it possible to grab the last digit number from every double-digit number with regex?

Tags: regex

So i try to grab every numbers that the last digit of it is number 2,5,0 from 1-30

```regex
\d{0,2}[2,5,0]
```

The result that i expect are
2,5,10,12,15,20,22,25,30

Instead i get all of the 20s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find a number ending with `0`, `2` or `5` within `1-30` range in a text you may use

```
\b(?:[25]|[12][250]|30)\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DNriUy/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Cb(%3F%3A%5B25%5D%7C%5B12%5D%5B250%5D%7C30)%5Cb):

[image]

To match these numbers as a standalone string replace word boundaries with `^` / `$` anchors:

```
^(?:[25]|[12][250]|30)$
```